# How specify number of core in parallel algorithm implemented in java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, parallel-processing

I have this following parallel algorithm below which was implemented using `Spark` and `Java`. But I am wondering how can I specify number of cores that it can use from the machine to see the performance. At first I thought I can just specify in `setMaster("local[2]")` providing the number of core it can use. But I don't think it works.

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.commons.lang.time.StopWatch;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

    public class Prime {

        List<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<>();

        //Method to calculate and count the prime numbers
        public void countPrime(int n){
            for (int i = 2; i < n; i++){
                boolean  isPrime = true;

                //check if the number is prime or not
                for (int j = 2; j < i; j++){
                    if (i % j == 0){
                        isPrime = false;
                        break;  // exit the inner for loop
                    }
                }

                //add the primes into the List
                if (isPrime){
                    primes.add(i);
                }
            }
        }



        //Main method to run the program
        public static void main(String[]args){
//
           StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
           watch.start();

            //creating javaSparkContext object
            SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("haha").setMaster("local");
            JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);

            //new prime object
            Prime prime = new Prime();
            prime.countPrime(1000000);

            //parallelize the collection
            JavaRDD<Integer> rdd = sc.parallelize(prime.primes,4);
            long count = rdd.filter(e  -> e == 2|| e % 2 != 0).count();


            watch.stop();
            System.out.println("Time took to run the process is " + watch);
            System.out.println("The number of prime 0 to 100000 after parallelization  is " + count);
            sc.stop();


        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `setMaster(local[*])` will indicate to Spark to use a number of threads equal to the available cores on the machine. However, based on your code, there are a few caveats as to why you may not see a performance gain:

1. The number of primes up to 1,000,000 is only about 78,000 elements. This is too small of a dataset to see much parallelism, especially since you're doing very simple processing of each element (a simple `filter` with basic arithmetic + `count`). This means Spark will likely spend a significant time on task overhead alone rather than doing actual processing.
2. The number of partitions you indicate in `sc.parallelize` is only 4. This means that no matter how many CPU cores are available, only 4 partitions are available to be processed, and hence you shouldn't expect a benefit beyond 4 cores.

I recommend generating a larger dataset, and using `rdd.getNumPartitions` to verify that the number of partitions you use is ~3-4x larger than the number of cores you have available, if possible. Each task should take at least a few seconds, otherwise you are likely paying a significant penalty in task overhead.

Some additional information on seeing the number of parallel tasks being executed & the number of partitions in the Spark UI can be found [here](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/performance_optimization/how_many_partitions_does_an_rdd_have.html).

Comment: Hi David, thank you for your answer. It was very helpful.